# Node.js - How to export both an object and a function

Tags: node.js, routes, export

I'm writing a router module for my express server, and I'm having trouble exporting both the router (for use in the server) and the handler functions used by the router (for unit tests). How do I export them both? The code looks like this:

```
const myRouter = express.Router();

function getHandler(req, res) {
    //handles a get request
}

myRouter.route('/').get(getHandler);
```

How can I export both the myRouter object and the getHandler functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can export an object with module.exports like this:

```
module.exports = {
   getHandler,
   myRouter
}
```

and then require these somewhere else like:

```
 const {getHandler, myRouter} = require('file path of router')
```

Answer (score 5):

To export use:

```
module.exports = myRouter;
module.exports = getHandler;
```

To require use:

```
var myRouter = require(//path to myRouter);
var getHandler = require(//path to getHandler);
```

Answer (score -1):

use exports function in the script you want to use outside the file like    `module.exports.myRouter = myRouter; module.exports.jsonObj = jsonObj;` and include in in the file you want to use the by using require like:    `var my_router = require(//path to routerscript);`

Comment: I've added `module.exports.myRouter = myRouter; module.exports.getHandler = getHandler;` to my code, but it throws the error `Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`